# How to determine how many times a character is repeated in a string?

Tags: java

I am having some trouble with writing a method that when prompted with a number returns how many times each value is repeated. For example, if the number 7846597 is entered the method would return:

```
0 - 0
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0
4 - 1
5 - 1
6 - 1
7 - 2
8 - 1
9 - 1
```

I know this would be most easily done with a loop, but I am not sure how to write the actual code. I also know that I need to convert the number value I get as an input into a string so I can use char methods.

This is my attempt:

```java
public double countOccurences(int num)
{
    String str = num + "";
    int goneThrough = 0;
    int count0 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;
    int count6 = 0;
    int count7 = 0;
    int count8 = 0;
    int count9 = 0;
    while(goneThrough <= str.length())
    {
        int value = 0;
        if(value >= 10){
            value = value * 0;
        }
        if(str.charAt(0) == 0)
            count0++;
        if(str.charAt(0) = 1)
            count1++;
    }
    return count0;
    return count1;
    return count2;
    return count3;
    return count4;
    return count5;
    return count6;
    return count7;
    return count8;
    return count9;
}
```

Comment: post your attempt

Comment: You could use an array with 10 elements, to store the count of each digit.

Comment: @accessviolation made the edit

Comment: When you have code like `int count0 = 0;   int count1 = 0;     int count2 = 0; ...`, it suggests the use of an array. And `return count0;  return count1;     return count2; ...` won't work. That also suggests use of an array.

Comment: Perhaps off topic: Converting the number input into a `String` is one approach. But, it isn't the only one. Another is to use successive mod and division operators:  `int digit = num % 10; num = num / 10;` for example.

Comment: `charAt` returns the code of the character at that location. The code of the character `'0'` is not 0.

Comment: If you are reading input from a prompt, why don't you read it directly as a string? Assume you are using `Scanner`, will be `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of `Scanner.nextInt()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`countOccurences(int num)` should return the number of occurrences of each digit as `int[10]`.

```
static int[] countOccurences(int num) {
    int[] result = new int[10];
    for ( ; num > 0; num /= 10)
        ++result[num % 10];
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 7846597;
    int[] output = countOccurences(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        System.out.println(i + " - " + output[i]);
}
```

output:

```
0 - 0
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0
4 - 1
5 - 1
6 - 1
7 - 2
8 - 1
9 - 1
```

Comment: Could also have `int[] result = new int[String.valueOf(num).length()]; ` inst of hard coding 10 in there (as a suggestion)

Comment: @AussieDev81 No, if `num` is `9`, it must return `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code where I used HashTable and stored number as string and count as value. This is optimized code where time complexity is O(n).

```
// code
import java.util.*;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    String number = "7846597";
    Hashtable<String, Integer> result = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<number.length(); i++){
        String current = "" + number.charAt(i);
        if(result.contains(current))   {
          int val = result.get(current);
          result.put(current, ++val);
        } else {
          result.put(current, 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(result);
  } 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without using a hashmap even if it is more complex, just haven't learned about them yet. Don't want to use things that I don't understand.

Comment: if you know ArrayList then you can also do with help of two arraylists, but time complexity would be O(n^2);

Answer (score 0):

Using int array of size 10 and increment value at index that maps to digit of 0-9.

```
public static void digitFrequencies(int number) {
    int[] arr = new int[10];

    for (char ch : String.valueOf(number).toCharArray()) {
      int digit = Character.digit(ch, 10);
      arr[digit] = arr[digit] + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + " - " + arr[i] + " ");
    }
  }
```